# Craps game: How do i get the while loop in this code from going into an infinite loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

this are comments that explain the game so you can test it, but the main problem is when you are suppose to run the while loop if you a point value then it becomes an infinite loop. How do I get it to not be an infinite loop?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Craps {
    private int roll1;
    private int roll2;
    private Random randGen;
    private int sum;
    private int thePoint = sum;
    private int bet;
    private int newSum;

    // instance classes
    public Craps() {
        randGen = new Random(); // this is the random generator
    }

    // when you win you double your money
    // when you lose you lose everything
    public void roll(int bet) { // you can bet as much money as you want
        roll1 = (randGen.nextInt(6) + 1);
        roll2 = (randGen.nextInt(6) + 1);
        sum = roll1 + roll2; // you must add the two rolls and that is your sum
        if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) { // if the sum is 2 you lose
            System.out.println("The sum is 2. You Lose!");
            System.out.println("Your credit:" + " " + bet * 0);
        } else if (sum == 7 || sum == 11) { // if it 7 you win
            System.out.println("The sum is 7. You Win!");
            System.out.println("Your credit:" + " " + bet * 2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You rolled a" + " " + sum + ". " + "That is your point. Roll      again.");
            sum = thePoint;

        }
    }

    public void rollAgain() {

        while (sum != 7 || sum != thePoint) { // whatever the the sum is that is not one of the numbers above becomes your point.
            roll1 = (randGen.nextInt(6) + 1);// you must role the die again until you get your point again the you win or until you get a 7 and then you lose.
            roll2 = (randGen.nextInt(6) + 1);
            sum = roll1 + roll2;
            if (thePoint == sum) { // if the point equals the sum you win
                System.out.println("You're on point. You Win!");
                System.out.println("Your credit:" + " " + bet * 2);
            } else if (sum == 7) { // if it equals 7 you lose.
                System.out.println("You got a 7. You lose!");
                System.out.println("Your credit:" + " " + bet * 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this an infinite loop? It will stop when you roll a total that equals 7 or thePoint.... it won't stop until it reaches either of those criteria,  you probably should check if they have money though.

Comment: Why do YOU not debug is as YOU test it?  Presumably, the loop exit conditions are not being met - why not debug it and find out why?

Comment: Also why is `rollAgain` a loop?

Comment: shouldn't it be while( sum != 7 && sum != thePoint ) ?

Comment: no it can be either one because if it is 7 than you lose but if it is thePoint then you win.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your loop condition.

`while (sum != 7 || sum != thePoint)` what happens here is that as soon as the first condition is met (sum is not seven), the loop starts executing.

if you change it to `while (sum != 7 && sum != thePoint)` then both these conditions need to be met - the loop only starts executing again if sum is not seven or the value of `thePoint`.

Comment: but I only need one of those conditions to be met. If the new roll becomes 7 then its suppose to be a lost but if it becomes thePoint which was the the sum of the first roll then its a win. Do i need to make seperate while statements for each condition?